# Unable to load ngRoute module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-routing

I'm working on a Node.js project that uses Angular, and I'm trying to implement multiple views and routing. I've followed the instructions outlined here for installing the angular-route.js file and dependent module:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

But I still get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blogApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/nomod?p0=ngRoute
```

Here are the parts that seem relevant from my controller and HTML files:

#### app.js

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="blogApp">
  <head>
    <title>Blog Posts</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="postController">

   // page content

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to working with Angular and Node, so any thoughts on this greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo (missing equal sign). This line:

```
<script src"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aughhh duh! Thank you so much for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

There is a very small typo in the script include for `ngRoute`. You had `src"https://` rather than `src="https://`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

You can debug these kinds of issues by checking the developer tools and making sure the script is loaded without error.

Comment: That's a good point. I could see it wasn't loading in the Network tab in Chrome's developer's tools, but I wasn't sure why. Thank you for looking!